# one-to-one and one-to-many modeling

Tags: django, one-to-many, modeling, one-to-one

So have people and addresses. A person may have more then one address but only one address can be marked as primary per person. The following are two ways I have considered doing it.

The first is awkward when saving as I have to save the person then the variant then the person again with the variant pk.

With the second approach it seems like the only way to prevent a person from having more then one primary address is to add validation in code.

```
# First approach
class Person(models.Model):
    primary_address = models.ForeignKey('Address')
    ...


class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    ...

# Second approach
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

class Address(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

Comment: Just to complicate things, is it possible for an address to be primary for one person and not for another? If so, variant 2 won't work.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Address are not shared between people.

Comment: OK, but it is very possible to imagine a situation where addresses can be shared. E.g. siblings attending the same school. That's why I brought it up.

Comment: Yeah that's something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I usually choose option #2 for situations like this. It is slightly more difficult to query, in that you sometimes have to do an additional query + a filter to select it, but it also gives you the option to save it more cleanly, as you mentioned.

With option #2, you can override the save method of the address model so that it marks all other addresses from the user as non-primary if itself is primary.